# Does Different Page Template for Mobile & Desktop Serving Same Content Affect SEO?

Tags: seo, mobile-website, google-search

I want to have different html designs for different versions but with the same content. I'm planning to achieve this by programmatically determining the requesting device before choosing which page template to return as a response.

I'm aware of the responsive template development frameworks out there but we are consciously not interested in taking that route because I want to have a different UXP suited for the requesting device.

My dev partner raised the concern that going by this approach will affect the site SEO. My question is, is this the case bearing in mind the the following items will remain constant ? :

1. The site URL will not change for both mobile & desktop
2. The site content will not change for both mobile with desktop (Only Layout & Markup will)

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, is this the case bearing in mind the the following items will remain constant?

No, Google will not penalize you by default for using different templates, since you will serve the same content (as a reminder, Google focusses on desktop content to establish mobile ranking). No worry.